# Collision in pygame not working (objects collide but code not triggering)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm making a Pygame program for a school project. The player character will pass through an enemy sprite without triggering the collision. How do I fix this?

CODE should be run if there is any overlap between the two sprites.

```
if CharY > thing_starty and CharY < thing_starty + Enemy2_height or CharY+PCHeight > thing_starty and CharY + PCHeight < thing_starty + Enemy2_height:
    if CharX > thing_startx and CharX < thing_startx + Enemy2_width or CharX + PCWidth > thing_startx and CharX + PCWidth < thing_startx + Enemy2_width:
        CODE
```

Comment: Have you tried to print out the values of your variables after each IF block is triggered?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) objects and [`.colliderect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) to check for the collision of two rectangles:

```py
# detects collisions
charRect  = pg.Rect(CharX, CharX, PCWidth, PCHeight)
enemyRect = pg.Rect(thing_startx, thing_starty, Enemy2_width, Enemy2_height)
if charRect.colliderect(enemyRect):
    # [...]
    # CODE
```

---

If you want to do the collision detection yourself, then you've got to check if the rectangles are overlapping in both dimensions.

A range [`x1`, `x1+w1`] overlaps a range [`x2`, `x2+w2`] if the following condition is fulfilled:

```
intersect = x1 < x2+w2 and x2 < x1+w1
```

Note, `w1` and `w2` have to be greater than 0.

Do this for both dimensions:

```py
if CharX < thing_startx + Enemy2_width  and thing_startx < CharX + PCWidht and \
   CharY < thing_starty + Enemy2_height and thing_starty < CharY + PCHeight
    # [...]
    # CODE
```